# JMH: invalid initial heap size

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments, microbenchmark, jmh

I test my program performance with JMH. And fail to configure heap size. I wondering why it doesn't work.

**Questions:**

1. Why JMH doesn't accept heap size configs?
2. Does JMH absorb idea heap size settings without `jvmArgs` method?

**Error:**

```
# Run progress: 0.00% complete, ETA 00:04:30
# VM invoker: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
# VM options: -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512M
# Fork: 1 of 1
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512M
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
<forked VM failed with exit code 1>
```

**Main Method:**

```
public static void main(String... args) throws RunnerException, IOException {
    Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
            .include(".*" + ArraySummatorBenchmarking.class.getSimpleName() + ".*")
            .warmupIterations(5)
            .measurementIterations(5)
            .forks(1)
            .jvmArgs("-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512M")
            .build();
    new Runner(opt).run();
}
```

**idea.vmoptions**

```
-server
-Xms2056m
-Xmx2056m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
```

**Main method options:**

```
-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512M
```

Comment: Does your computer have enough memory for multiple VMs each with 2G of initial heap?

Comment: Try to use `.jvmArgs("-Xms2048m", "-Xmx2048m", "-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512M")` (vararg with a single item per option instead of a single string that contains all options).

Comment: @OlegEstekhin you are right. It works!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JMH uses [Runtime.exec(String[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) to launch a forked VM. This method assumes a single command-line token per array item, and it will properly escape spaces inside tokens.

It means that when you pass a `"-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512M"` string as an argument it is treated as a single argument that happens to contain spaces inside instead of three separate space-separated arguments.

Thus the proper way to specify multiple JVM arguments in JMH is to use a separate string value for each separate argument:

```
Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
        ...
        .jvmArgs("-Xms2048m", "-Xmx2048m", "-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512M")
        ...
```